# What is the percent chance of laying an egg?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

What is the percent chance for a tamed dinosaur to lay an egg (excluding Dodos)?

In the wiki on [Dinosaur eggs](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dinosaur_Eggs), under the section **Frequency and Probability** the frequency of an egg laying is stated:

> A mate-boosted female creature will have a chance to lay an egg every 17 minutes.

Along with that the probability of Dodos are stated, but have a different mechanic then regular Dinosaurs:

> Dodos have different egg laying mechanic: They have a chance of 13% to lay an egg instead of a feces when defecating, which happens randomly after 100 to 300 seconds. They can also be forced to lay an egg with relative ease by force feeding stimberries.

I have not found any resources stating the actual percent chance of laying an egg, is such information known?